# TypeError: console.table is not a function

Tags: vercel, sveltekit, console.log

Deploying a SvelteKit app to Vercel that has a `+server.ts` endpoint which uses `console.table`.

Hitting the endpoint results in a `500` response, just because `console.table` failed.

```
TypeError: console.table is not a function
    at (../../../../src/routes/api/chat-v4/+server.ts:133:12)
    at (../../../../node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/endpoint.js:43:17)
    at (../../../../node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:401:16)
    at (../../../../node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/respond.js:271:19)
```

Why is this the case? Is `console.table` not supported in the Vercel runtime?

It works perfectly fine when running SvelteKit locally. The vercel build is successful too.

Running `npm run preview` works fine using `@sveltejs/adapter-vercel`.

Changing the node version to `18` (matching the vercel deployment) works as well.

I am guessing this might have to do with Vercel logs? Inability to handle `console.table`?